# Convert incoming OSC message to TUIO 2Dcur

Tags: javascript, udp, google-chrome-app, osc

Here's what works right now:

- Microcontroller reads 2 touch surfaces, outputs them as a single OSC bundle (using [this library](https://github.com/CNMAT/OSC)) every 10ms over USB.
- Chrome app receives these OSC bundles (using [this library](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js)) over USB via `chrome.serial` and displays them on a canvas element

So far, so good.

Next, I want to send these messages over UDP to a TUIO client.  As a first step, I made sure I can send OSC messages over UDP (again using [osc.js](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js)) and indeed this works.

Here's some example messages as seen by my Chrome app:

```
// console.log(JSON.stringify(msg)) gives results like this:
{"address":"/p0","args":[2369,1683,170]}
{"address":"/p1","args":[1906,1752,137]}
{"address":"/p1","args":[1906,1752,137]}
```

## How do I turn these into TUIO messages?

I've tried to connect this Chrome app to various example TUIO client implementations (Node, browser, Ruby, Python, Processing) and the results are either to crash on an exception due to a malformed message, or to simply do nothing at all.

Here are some message formats I've tried, with no success:

```
osc.send(msg);
osc.send({address:"/tuio/2Dcur", args:msg.args});
osc.send({address:"/tuio/2Dcur", args:["alive"].concat(msg.args)});
osc.send({address:"/tuio/2Dcur", args:["set"].concat(msg.args)});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered what I was missing.  The TUIO clients I've used so far apparently expect [OSC bundles](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js#sending-osc-bundles), so my app should send a bundle like so:

```
my_osc.send({
  timeTag: osc.timeTag(0),
  packets: [
    {address:'/tuio/2Dcur', args: ['alive'].concat(my_session_id)},
    {address:'/tuio/2Dcur', args: ['set'].concat(my_session_id).concat(my_data)}
  ]
});
```